# ARGUMENTS type in pascal

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal, turbo-pascal

I want to make a procedure to write a color text, similar writeln();

```
writelncolor(color:byte;args:arguments);
```

But when I compile it, Pascal found an error not found type **Arguments**

[image]

I looked in Lazarus, in unit System, it have **writeln** procedure:

```
writeln(args:arguments);
```

Please help me, thanks.
[image: Image1]

Comment: In your procedure you have written the second argument as `args:argument` Note, it should be of type `arguments` (plural, ending in s)

Comment: FYI, I have voted to close this question as the cause is a simple typographical error. The question will not have value for future readers.

Comment: @Tom Arguments is just an IDE shim for the Writeln intrinsic. See the dupe.

Comment: Ah, ok @David, for a brief moment I thought here was something to put behind my ear ;)

Comment: `Arguments` is not a real type. `Writeln` and others are so called "compiler magic" functions (currently, also called: "intrinsics"), which are recognized by the compiler as special and, depending on the parameters passed, are compiled as combinations of several different, hidden, runtime functions, or sometimes just as casts or inline code.

Comment: Yes. That's what it says at the dupe.

Comment: @David: assuming you meant what I wrote: no, it doesn't, at least not exactly.

Comment: Probably the difference is that Marco's post was technically accurate, and used the right terminology, on account of he being one of the fpc developers